How to fix wsl error [process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
I installed zsh but decided to remove it but got this error on my terminal
<3>WSL (412) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh failed 2
<3>WSL (412) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:508: Create process not expected to return
[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart.
I tried to acces wsl with bash using
wsl -e /bin/bash

and tried to remove zsh
sudo apt remove zsh
sudo apt purge zsh

i hoped it would uninstall zsh, and the purge command will remove any configuration files associated with zsh.

if you get this on your windows terminal

There is no distribution with the supplied name. Error code:
Wsl/Service/WSL_E_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND

try

wsl --list --verbose

This command will list all installed WSL distributions along with their names.
now to reset your bash access wsl distro with bash and run this

wsl -d YourDistroName -e /bin/bash
and run this command and change the line that contains "username:x:1000:1000:User Name:/home/username:/usr/bin/zsh
" to "username:x:1000:1000:User Name:/home/username:/usr/bin/bash"
sudo nano /etc/passwd

